# How to stack two variable width divs, and then have text wrap to the side of both

Tags: css

I've been stuck on this seemingly simple issue.

I want to take two divs of variable width, and stack them left aligned. (basically the normal behavior of two block elements). But then I want to have text wrap around both divs.

My problem is that the first div is of variable width, and I can't figure out how to get the text to wrap both elements, and not leave whitespace making up the difference in div widths.

Example:  I = Div 1 / A = Div 2 , T = Text

This is how I'd like it to work.

```
IIITT
ATTTT
```

If I float the divs, they always end up next to one another as such

```
IIAAT
TTTTT
```

If I try and close both div's in the same div and then float it, the text leaves white space

```
IIITT
A  TT
```

So I'm having trouble conceptually thinking about how I should organize my elements.

Comment: Do you have any examples that could help me understand? The letters are kind confusing me, maybe a image would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you divs at before the text, float them left like you were before, but also add

```
clear:left;
```

to your divs.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4GKrB/

Answer (score 1):

If you set a CSS value of `clear: both` on your divs, I think that'll solve your issue. See: http://jsfiddle.net/wLX9Z/1/

Comment: Exactly right. I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks much!